# Fail to bind azure queue storage with azure functions(scheduler trigger) in portal

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I am building a Azure function app to access the Azure Queue Storage(Scheduler Trigger), retrieve messages, and send emails using SendGrid.

I've spent a lot of time debugging and crawling StackOverFlow but still received the same error message.

Here is the error message.

> [Error] Exception while executing function:
>   Functions.ScheduledMailCSharpHobby. mscorlib: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage:
>   Settings must be of the form "name=value".

FILE: **run.csx**

```html
#r "SendGrid"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;


public static Mail Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    var today = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
    log.Info($"Generating daily report for {today} at {DateTime.Now}");
    
    Mail message = new Mail()
    {
        Subject = $"Daily Report for {today}"
    };

    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("serverlessbdbxxxxxxx");
    // Get queue... create if does not exist.
    CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
    CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("memberqueue");
    // Peek at the next message
    CloudQueueMessage peekedMessage = queue.PeekMessage();

    // Display message.
    log.Info(peekedMessage.AsString);

    var mail_content = peekedMessage.AsString;

    Content content = new Content
    {
        Type = "text/plain",
        Value = $"Hi! {mail_content}"
    };

    message.AddContent(content);
    return message;
}
```

FILE: **function.json**

```html
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "name": "myTimer",
      "schedule": "0 0 17 * * *",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "sendGrid",
      "name": "$return",
      "direction": "out",
      "apiKey": "AzureWebJobsSendGridApiKey",
      "from": "Azure Functions <samples@functions.com>",
      "to": "xxxx@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is caused by this line.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("serverlessbdbxxxxxxx");
```

To access the Storage account connection string, you need to

1. Store the connection string in Application settings of Function app on portal.

   [image]

   [image]
2. Get the connection string with GetEnvironmentVariable().

   ```
   CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("StorageConnectionString"));
   ```

Comment: Hi Jerry, thank you for your reply. The issue solved!! Thank you for your kindness help.

Comment: @WinnieChen You're welcome, you could accept my answer to close your question.